# performance overhead of distributed transactions

Tags: sql-server, performance, transactions, jta, distributed-transactions

(When testing an implementation of distributed transactions using Atomikos, I noticed an large overhead (a transaction that took 30 milliseconds without using XA took 160 with XA)

It looks like most of the time is spent in "Prepare" and in "Commit".

For the testing I used the (unrealistic) scenario of a transaction involving a single data source (Microsoft SQL Server), with no actual updates.  I would expect minimal overhead in such a case.

So my questions are:

- Is this a "normal" overhead?
- If not, where should I look next? (my best guess would be to use SQL Server Profiler to see if the time is spent inside the Database)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this long wait only happens on the first time you use the transaction.

That happens because a connection is established to the servers in order to start the transaction. After the first time, every time you call OpenTransaction should not take that long.

You can test it by yourself. Without closing the app, call a transaction twice.

Of couse some **overhead will exist**, because when you use distributed transactions you commit your data twice or more depending on how many server you use(once in each server). But it should not be that long as you have described.

Comment: Thanks Rafael.  The delays I'm seeing are not limited to the first transaction (and the "UserTransaction" object is reused).  I'm curious - have you had a good experience with distributed transactions?  I've been advised to avoid them and to implement an application specific mechanism instead.

Comment: I have good experiences with distributed transactions. I have a software that is running using it for 6 months. Maybe this overhead you are seen is something about the network or the servers (maybe they are to heavily used). But it will be hard to tell you what problem is without seeing your database and software.

Comment: You should also double check if you have latest sql server patches and also the load of your servers. It would be nice if you could post the query you are running.